# Should hardcoded data in a function be static?

Tags: php

When I have hardcoded data in a function I could just initialize the variable normally:

```
function check_country() {
  $countries = array(
    'aa',
    'ab',
    'ae',
    ...
  );

}
```

Will PHP just make `$countries` *point* to the literal data in memory or will it *copy over* all the initialization data to a new ZVAL or whatever?

If it does the latter that would be basically equivalent to this, wouldn't it?

```
function check_country() {
  $countries = array();
  $countries[] = 'aa';
  $countries[] = 'ab';
  $countries[] = 'ae';

}
```

An alternative would be to make the variable static and initialize it like this:

```
function check_country() {
  static $countries;

  if (!isset($countries))
  {
    $countries = array(
      'aa',
      'ab',
      'ae',
      ...
    );
  }

}
```

Is this technique a) faster and does it b) require twice the memory?

Comment: [`static`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) really has nothing to do with this. You use `static` when you want to change a method or an instance variable to be tied to a class rather than an object.

Comment: "is it better" --- better from what perspective? Optimizations should be preceded by a profiling that points to a particular place as a bottleneck. This is barely a bottleneck.

Comment: @mc10 see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Comment: @Esailija Oh gosh PHP uses the same term to refer to different concepts... I've been a bit rusty on my PHP

Comment: @mc10, PHP invented nothing there. You can do the same thing in C++ and Java, at least. (And C++ has at least one more use for the `static` keyword.)

Comment: @zneak Java isn't the same though. Everything is tied to the class, so you're actually just creating a class property. It works in the same way but it's a different implementation. _That_ actually makes sense.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't bother with that. According to Joel Spolsky, a developer needs two things to be great: be smart, and Get Things Done. You need the two of them. So while thinking about this probably shows you're smart, giving attention to such tiny details certainly doesn't help you to Get Things Done. Pick one, be consistent with it, and that should be it.

Comment: @zerkms: In terms of CPU cycles. Of course they are cheap nowadays but on the other hand the `static` technique is only 3 lines more.

Comment: @mc10, I fail to see the difference between `static int foo = 4;` inside a method body in Java and `static $foo = 4;` inside a function body in PHP.

Comment: @zneak The former ties it to the class, the latter just "automagically" works in PHP.

Comment: @AndreKR: how about memory? Do you really want it to be kept until script dies? There are no completely free optimizations. And it's actually `0` additional lines - just prepend the variable initialization with `static` and it will be run just once.

Comment: @zneak: Good point, I'll add it to the question because if someone can explain if anything is copied there that would also answer the question about the memory.

Comment: @mc10 java has plenty of different uses for `static`, like static initialization blocks and static imports

Comment: By the way, I actually believe it would make a difference in a function that is for example called 10000 times per one web page hit.

Comment: @AndreKR: "I actually believe" --- prove that :-) Belief is something should be avoid when you program ;-) PS: if you run something 10k times - it makes sense to think about algorithm optimization, not opcode micro optimizations

Comment: Maybe I didn't convey the essence of my question properly. I added another paragraph with further clarification of what I was afraid of. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- To make a variable static just prepend it with `static` keyword. No additional checks like `if (!isset($countries))` required;
- The "dynamic" implementation consumes a bit more CPU, because each time the function is called another new local variable is created;
- The "static" implementation consumes a bit more memory, since static variables are allocated in the heap (like global ones) and they live there until script finishes execution.

Conclusion: you won't notice any reasonable difference between them (as long as you don't create several-megabytes-size-array) - so choose the one you like better (presumably the first).

Comment: Does it make a difference if I use `static $countries = array (...)` or `static $countries; $countries = array(...)`?

Comment: @AndreKR: yep. In the first case it will be initialized with `array` just once at first run. In the second - it will overwrite the current value with new `array` each time

Answer (score 0):

Next to what [zerkms answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13964206/367456), for the `static` variant, you can be initialize the variable and spare the `if`:

```
function check_country() {
  static $countries = array(
      'aa',
      'ab',
      'ae',
      ...
    );
  }    
}
```

**As long as** the initial data is of static nature (constant), too (like in your case).